# CSS: Background size contain and positioning in IE/Safari

Tags: css, background-image

Hello there I am a bit confused by the behaviour on a responsive CSS background image in IE11/Safari 5  which works well in Chrome and Firefox:

```
#contentheader_logo_inner {
    background:url('images/logo.svg') right top no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:200px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The thing is that the svg background image is perfectly contained within the dynamically scaled div (which has a width/height in percent), but in IE and Safari it is always displayed LEFT instead of RIGHT when scaling.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
#contentheader_logo_inner {
    background:url('images/logo.svg') right top no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; /* thats wrong */
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:200px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Change:

```
#contentheader_logo_inner {
    background:url('images/logo.svg') right top no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%; /* full size background */
    background-origin: content-box; /* this placing the background the words place (content-box) */
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:200px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the tip however it is not completley solving the problem. Your solution is constant in every browser but the background image is always centered and not aligned to the right of the element.

Comment: Note: The width of the element #content_logo_inner may have a larger width than height, vice versa its working